# How do people in Yerushalayim manage with Purim on Friday?

Tags: purim, meal-seudah, leil-shabbat

In Diaspora, the only time Purim is on Friday is when 1st Pesach is on Sunday. That's a rare occurrence. I vaguely recall what I did with managing *Se'udat Purim* on Friday and squeezing it in between needing to be at work.

The 1st day of Pesach occurs on Shabbat much more frequently - as a matter of fact, including this year, 4 of the last 5 years had that. So, in Yerushalayim 4 of the last 5 Purim were on Friday.

I gather that at least since Friday is a non-work day (and I guess most businesses would be closed on Purim, anyway) that aspect makes things easier in Yerushalayim, etc. than here.

But, still it must be a bit hectic. How do people in Yerushalayim manage squeezing in *Seudat Purim* between all the other activities and preparations for Shabbat? I'm especially curious to get the perspective from families that have lots of young children and they need constant attention, entertainment  and supervision

Comment: I asked my sister. She said "a lot of crazy running around"

Comment: Am in Yerushalaim today so briefly before shabbat comes in. Either you start the seuda at 11am or you start at 4pm, interrupt for kiddush and continue into shabbat. You daven maariv after birkat hamazon. Bn I will aim to write this up more fully after shabbat if no one does before

Comment: As you said this happens everywhere. Seemingly everyone manages it the same way. I don't understand the question.

Comment: @mbloch that's not unique to yerushalayim. Everyone does that when it's on Friday

Comment: @DoubleAA regular Purim on Friday is rare, it happens 11.5% of the time - last time in 2010 - so it is legitimate some of us forgot

Comment: @mbloch it only happens in Yerushalayim 28% of the time. Not so common either. This is not relevant to anything I've said here though.